# Using ColdFusion, how can I retrieve all public documents from a given Google Drive folder?

Tags: coldfusion, google-drive-api

For my current project I'm stuck working with ColdFusion. My question is, how much work will I have to put into re-writing library functionality before I can retrive **"public on the web"** files from a given folder on Google Drive? In other words, I have a folderID predefined and need to retrieve all public files within it.

This would be the only functionality I need, so I don't want to code full functionality for the GD API if I only need a small segment.

I know there is a [ColdFusion implementation of OAuth](http://oauth.riaforge.org/), though I haven't yet looked into what it is capable of. My main concern is whether I can completely avoid authentication with the given circumstances I'm working with.

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `how much work will I have to put into re-writing library functionality` -- is this really a question?

Comment: @Sergii, [it is most definitely a question](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/question) and it is also a completely valid one. Don't appreciate the downvote. The point was, for the limited functionality that I need, how much of the library functionality needs to be recreated in CF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Coldfusion, but you can [retrieve the list of public files in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) by sending an [authorized](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) GET request to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='1234567' in parents and 'anyone' in readers
```

where '1234567' is the folder ID.

Remember to URL-encode the query parameter so that it looks like the following when is sent to the API:

```
'1234567'%20in%20parents%20and%20'anyone'%20in%20readers
```

You can also try the same requests using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).

Comment: He could simply use that GET request in a `<cfhttp>` call.